# Unable to use 'vi' on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vim, vi, tcl

Whenever I try to open any text file using `vi` or `vim`, I get the following error,

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libtcl8.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I compiled and installed tcl 8.6 from source to take care of this dependency but it still doesnt work. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tcl8.5
```

Comment: not `sduo`, `sudo`!

Comment: @Danatela Right you are, fixed.

Comment: @minerz There seems to be no package by that name. However I tried installing `tcl8.5` but it says that its already the newest version.

Comment: @JTG Try the new command.

Comment: @minerz That gave me `E: Invalid operation tcl8.5`

Comment: @JTG Are you sure that the command's right? In any case, this new one should work if you copy/paste the whole line.

Comment: @minerz Thanks a lot, this worked. It took care of the tcl dependency and now I can use `vi` :-) . Couldn't vote up your answer due to the 15 rep rule :P

Answer (score 1):

Please install vim using

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

and use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

if there are any dependency problems.

Comment: I tried this, but still same error :/

Comment: paste the output of the following command: find / -name "libtcl8.5*"

Comment: This gave me a blank output.